# I want to get location in a variable and want to use this variable to apply conditions

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have two pages. One is login page and in other page i am finding my location using Geolocation. But in login page I want to get that variable from location file and apply conditions on that variable.....

```
    <script>
    function displayLocation(latitude,longitude){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var method = 'GET';
    var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?           latlng='+latitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true';
    var async = true;

    request.open(method, url, async);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var address = data.results[1];
            var check = address.formatted_address;
            document.write(check);


        }
    };
    request.send();
};

var successCallback = function(position){
    var x = position.coords.latitude;
    var y = position.coords.longitude;
    displayLocation(x,y);
};

var errorCallback = function(error){
    var errorMessage = 'Unknown error';
    switch(error.code) {
        case 1:
            errorMessage = 'Permission denied';
            break;
        case 2:
            errorMessage = 'Position unavailable';
            break;
        case 3:
            errorMessage = 'Timeout';
            break;
    }
    document.write(errorMessage);
};

var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 1000,
    maximumAge: 0
};
```

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback,errorCallback,options);

When I call this file in my login file then it only displays location but login page contents disappears....Please help me

Comment: I want to use the variable in which location is saved and want to apply condition on it in login file.